# Where does philosopher work, and what does he do on a normal work day?

Tags: work

I am programmer I sit in front of PC and produce web systems (in a nutshell).
Where does philosopher work and what does philosopher do in his work place?
**Update:** Teaching others does not count, as it is by definition teaching (of philosophy).

Comment: If you wrote papers on philosophy at your computer you'd be a philosopher. Perhaps try academia.stackexchange to find out what professors do all day. Teach, write books, write grant proposals, read, think. Of course if you were a CS major you know about the dining philosophers! They alternately eat and think.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic. Could we migrate this one to academia.SE?

Comment: @user4894 So basically `lecturing others and creating teaching materials` is your answer.

Comment: @LIUFA If you count "producing original works and research" as "creating teaching materials" then yes. On the other hand that would be what basically any academic does.

Comment: I sit in front of a computer.

Comment: @DBK I just realised that you are suggesting to migrate this question based on sole answer that you can give.

Comment: It does not really seem appropriate for academia's stack without some reframing -- but I've asked the mods there if they'd like it.

Comment: Rilkes answer is that they work in *solitude* - but he was a poet.

Comment: I disagree this question should be migrated.  What better question for philosophy than what its purpose is?  That's merely philosophy philosophizing about itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The philosopher's only business is *concepts*; and the concept belongs only to philosophy.

Just as scientists and mathematicians create functions (using variables) and artists/writers create compositions (using variations,) philosophers recover or create concepts (using pure variances).

In their [article on Deleuze](http://www.iep.utm.edu/deleuze), IEP discusses this problem:

> [a concept] is a multiplicity, not in itself a single thing, but an assemblage of components which must retain coherence with the others for the concept to remain itself (in this sense, it closely resembles the Spinozist body). These components are singularities: “‘a’ possible world, ‘a’ face, ‘some’ words . . .” (WP 20), and yet become indiscernible when a part of a concept. Each concept also has a relationship to other concepts by way of the similar problems that they address, and by having similar component elements...

They discuss this last point about the relations between concepts in terms of resonance and redundancy; concepts *vibrate* with one another.

--In passing, most professors of philosophy won't self-identify as "philosophers" today, but rather will indicate they "study" or "teach" philosophy. But I thought it might be interesting to try to speak to the terms of your question; it's difficult to understand [what philosophy is](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0231079893) if you don't grasp that philosophers do *create* something, just like artists and writers and scientists and mathematicians, and that what they create is concepts.

Comment: You misinterpreted my question, and for whatever reason assumed that I don't think that philosophers create or produce. Question is what do philosophers do on a working day? Where do they work?

Comment: Yeah, @LUIFA I'm afraid I don't get the "where" question -- many thinkers work in an academic context as professors or researchers, so "a university" would likely be the answer there?